# Function ping+() into .bashrc doesn't work

Tags: bash, function, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've this problem.
My machine is windows 10, latest version.

I'm installed cygwin, and into my bashrc I've this function:

```
ping+()
{
        host=$1
        par_1=$2
        par_2=$3
        par_3=$4
        ping $host $par_1 $par_2 $par_3 | xargs -n1 -i bash -c 'echo [`date +"%Y-%m-%d | %H:%M:%S"`] " {}"'
}
```

Works fine:

```
Luca[~] :> ping+ www.google.it
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:23]  Pinging www.google.it [74.125.71.94] with 32 bytes of data:
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:23]  Reply from 74.125.71.94: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=43
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:24]  Reply from 74.125.71.94: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=43
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:25]  Reply from 74.125.71.94: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=43
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:26]  Reply from 74.125.71.94: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=43
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:26]  Ping statistics for 74.125.71.94:
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:26]  Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:26]  Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
[2018-11-28 | 20:41:26]  Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 31ms, Average = 29ms
```

But if I put this code into .bashrc on "ubuntu windows filesystem" I receive this error:

```
luca[/mnt/c/Users/Luca] :> source /home/luca/.bashrc
ping+(): command not found
```

Most likely the "+" after "ping" it's not accepted.
How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks
Luca

Comment: Use a function name without a `+`?

Comment: This happens when you have extglob enabled

Comment: `+` isn't guaranteed to be valid in shell function names. The POSIX standard tells which names are guaranteed to work -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05 describing function declaration syntax, which tells you that the relevant definition of which names are valid is that at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235

Comment: To quote the standard: *In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a name is not a digit.*. Thus, a shell is only required to support names with underscores, alpha characters, and digits -- and digits not in the first position. `+` is in none of those categories, so support for it, when present at all, is a nonportable extension and should not be relied on.

Comment: Ivo Yordanov says he wishes to delete his answer. He can't do so because you've accepted it. If you want to allow it to be deleted, you can unaccept it by clicking the check mark again. (You're under no obligation to do so, or to accept another answer.)

Comment: Luca unaccept it, please so @Keith Thompson can have his way... Tired of wasting my time on this. At my profile you have a link to my Linkedin account. Contact me if you need further assistance on this. Willing to take it out of stackoverflow.

Comment: @IvoYordanov: Please stop trying to make this about me.

Comment: @Luca, ...btw, `xargs -I{} bash -c '...{}...'` opens the door to security risks: The value substituted for `{}` can be parsed as code instead of data. It's much safer to use `xargs bash -c '..."$1"...' _ {}`, which keeps data out-of-band from code, so a value containing `$(rm -rf ~)` (as a particularly malicious example) doesn't *actually* delete your home directory.

Comment: @Luca, ...as a less-critical note, `date` is fairly slow to run (and telling `xargs` to start up a new copy of `bash` or `sh` for each line of output is even moreso). Replacing `xargs` with a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop will reduce CPU overhead quite a bit; ditching `date` for bash 4.3's `%(...)T` capability in `printf`, even moreso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of an odd interaction between shell functions with a `'+'` character in their names and bash's `extglob` option.  Most likely you have `extglob` disabled in your shell under Cygwin, and enabled in your "ubuntu windows filesystem" configuration.

I haven't figured out why `extglob` has this particular side effect. It may be a bug in bash. It might even be a bug that `bash` accepts `ping+` as a function name, depending on just what the relevant standards and other documentation say about the correct syntax of a function name.

The simplest solution is to use a name that doesn't end with a `+` character.

If you really want to use the name `ping+` for your function, a workaround is to unset the `extglob` option when defining the function. (You can still invoke it with the name `ping+` whether `extglob` is set or not.)

For example, you could have this in your `.bashrc`:

```
shopt -u extglob
ping+() {
    host=$1
    par_1=$2
    par_2=$3
    par_3=$4
    ping $host $par_1 $par_2 $par_3 | xargs -n1 -i bash -c 'echo [`date +"%Y-%m-%d | %H:%M:%S"`] " {}"'
}
shopt -s extglob
```

(This forces `extglob` to be set. If you want to leave it in its initial state, that's a bit more complicated. You'd have to parse the output of `shopt extglob` to determine whether it's set or unset. But you probably want to set it unconditionally anyway.)

Another solution is to use an executable shell script rather than a function. For example, this script is equivalent to your function:

```
#!/bin/bash

host="$1"
par_1="$2"
par_2="$3"
par_3="$4"
ping $host $par_1 $par_2 $par_3 | xargs -n1 -i bash -c 'echo [`date +"%Y-%m-%d | %H:%M:%S"`] " {}"'
```

Create a file called `ping+` with the above contents, make it executable with `chmod +x`, and copy it to a directory in your `$PATH` such as `$HOME/bin`. (There's no need to install it in a system directory such as `/usr/bin`. If you want it to be available to all users on the system, you can install it in a system-wide directory such as `/usr/local/bin`. The `/usr/bin` directory is intended for commands provided by the operating system itself.)

This works because the rules for command names are simpler and less restrictive than the rules for shell function names.

Here's a simpler and more reliable version (it avoids any issues with shell metacharacters in the arguments).

```
#!/bin/bash

ping "$@" | xargs -n1 -i bash -c 'echo [`date +"%Y-%m-%d | %H:%M:%S"`] " {}"'
```

Or better (since `xargs` can enable command substitution attacks, as Charles Duffy points out):

```
#!/bin/bash

ping "$@" | while read -r line ; do echo "[$(date +'%Y-%m-%d | %H:%M:%S')] $line" ; done
```

Comment: Re: what the standards say -- "An implementation may allow other characters in a function name as an extension" is explicit, so bash *is* permitted (but not required) to allow function names beyond [the XBD Name definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I would argue that allowing `ping+` as a function name if and only if `extglob` is defined is a bug.

Comment: @IvoYordanov: You're right, my mistake. The numbering threw me off.

Comment: BTW, it probably wouldn't be a bad idea to remove `xargs` from the "more reliable version" entirely. Putting `{}` inside a `-c` string is an invitation to command substitution attacks (even if implementing one here might require something tricky, like a hostile reverse DNS entry).